# Copy assign a map if element is not assignable

Tags: c++

```
struct const_int { const int x = 1; };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, const_int> map0;
    std::unordered_map<int, const_int> map1 { map0 }; // OK
    map1 = map0; // Compile-time error
    return 0;
}
```

This code works in Visual C++ 2017, but fails with compile error in Visual C++ 2019:

```
14.23.27911\include\list(1210): error C2280: 'std::pair<_Kty,_Ty> &std::pair<_Kty,_Ty>::operator =(volatile const std::pair<_Kty,_Ty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
            with
            [
                _Kty=int,
                _Ty=const_int
            ]
```

Which compiler version has correct implementation, or behavior is not defined in this case?

Comment: btw. `map1 = std::move(map0)` works

Comment: which version of g++ compiler are you using?

Comment: I mean c++ version

Comment: Here is a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/589006/compilation-error-with-unordered-map-with-a-struct.html) for the same thing but using `const_int` as key: Apparently it is no bug...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting [Billy Robert O'Neil III from visual studio developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/589006/compilation-error-with-unordered-map-with-a-struct.html) this is not a bug:

> This is not a bug. `unordered_map` is an allocator-aware container, and the assignment operation of allocator-aware containers requires that the `value_type` be copy assignable - see [`containers.allocatoraware`](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.allocatoraware) - and then [`unord.req`](https://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#10) says that for the purposes of requirements in the unordered containers, one looks to `key_type` and `mapped_type` instead.
>
> This happened to work in previous releases of Visual C++ because `std::list`, out of which `std::unordered_map` is constructed, used to deallocate all nodes during an assignment operation, so even though it was permitted to assign elements, we happened not to. But that meant that assigning 100 values into a list already containing 100 elements would do 200 unnecessary calls to the allocator: deallocating all 100 old nodes, then allocating 100 new nodes. The behavior change you observe is because in VS2019 Update 2, we implemented an optimization to reuse already-allocated nodes in an assignment.

Comment: Yeah, sounds reasonable. So VS2019 did performance optimization in unordered_map implementation that triggered this.

Comment: That's a very interesting argument. However I wonder how it fits to the [`operator=` description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator%3D) - The implementation is only required to replace the contents (which would work for non-`const` and `const` likewise), so I don't directly see a contradiction here. MSVC's behavior is still unclear to me.

Comment: Oh, I've found it. Indeed it seems to be true.

Comment: Shouldn't they just placement-new construct the elements instead?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [@MofX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57406475/1753435) I'd like to add some resources here, also because the quoted text contains invalid links.

From [[unord.map]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.map) (emphasis mine):

> An `unordered_­map` satisfies all of the requirements of a container, of
>   an unordered associative container, and of an **allocator-aware**
>   container.

This leads to [[container.requirements.general]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.requirements.general#16), where for the assignment expression in Table 86 the requirements are (emphasis mine):

> *Requires:  T is CopyInsertable into X and **CopyAssignable***.

Of course, the type used in the OP's example `struct const_int { const int x = 1; };` is *not* copy assignable (due to the `const` and no user-defined assignment operator) and therefore the compilation fails.

I hope this makes it clearer.

*(Disclaimer: Initially I was convinced MSVC has a bug here but I was proven wrong)*

Comment: This would have been a huge edit containing additional information that I have researched (and this could have been been potentially wrong). I don't think it would fit as edit.