# Creating std::vector of non-copyable types

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, stdvector

I am using MSVC 2015, where  I have a type which can be moved, but not copied. From what I gather, since C++11, the container type doesn't have to copyable. However, on creating a std::vector of such type, I get numerous compilation errors from xmemory header (which says that a bunch of std::allocator member functions require the copy constructor).

I have tried writing a minimal test case but that does compile fine. The existing code is a huge piece of code which I cannot copy and paste here. What can be the possible things that I can look into to figure out why the copy constructor is being requested?

As requested the error messages I get are:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(737): error C2280: 'MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)': attempting to reference a deleted function (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  c:\<some path>\src\../inc/MyClass.h(161): note: see declaration of 'MyClass::MyClass' (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  c:\<some path>\../inc/MyClass.h(161): note: see declaration of 'MyClass::MyClass' (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(857): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct<_Objty,_Ty>(_Objty *,_Ty &&)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass,
3>              _Objty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(857): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct<_Objty,_Ty>(_Objty *,_Ty &&)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass,
3>              _Objty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(996): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,_Ty>(std::allocator<_Ty> &,_Objty *,_Ty &&)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Alloc=std::allocator<MyClass>,
3>              _Ty=MyClass,
3>              _Objty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0(995): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,_Ty>(std::allocator<_Ty> &,_Objty *,_Ty &&)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Alloc=std::allocator<MyClass>,
3>              _Ty=MyClass,
3>              _Objty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory(278): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>::construct<_Ty,MyClass>(_Ty *,MyClass &&)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory(278): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>::construct<_Ty,MyClass>(_Ty *,MyClass &&)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory(305): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt *std::_Uninitialized_move_al_unchecked1<_InIt,_FwdIt,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt,std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>> &,std::_General_ptr_iterator_tag,std::_Any_tag)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _FwdIt=MyClass *,
3>              _InIt=MyClass *,
3>              _Ty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory(318): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt *std::_Uninitialized_move_al_unchecked<_Iter,_Iter,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt,std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _FwdIt=MyClass *,
3>              _Iter=MyClass *,
3>              _Ty=MyClass,
3>              _InIt=MyClass *
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(1660): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt *std::_Uninitialized_move<_Iter,MyClass*,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt,std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _FwdIt=MyClass *,
3>              _Iter=MyClass *,
3>              _Ty=MyClass,
3>              _InIt=MyClass *
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(1605): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MyClass *std::vector<MyClass,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Umove<MyClass*>(_Iter,_Iter,MyClass *)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass,
3>              _Iter=MyClass *
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(1605): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'MyClass *std::vector<MyClass,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Umove<MyClass*>(_Iter,_Iter,MyClass *)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass,
3>              _Iter=MyClass *
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(1601): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<MyClass,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Reallocate(unsigned __int64)'
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
3>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(1631): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<MyClass,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Reallocate(unsigned __int64)' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass
3>          ] (compiling source file src\MyClass.cpp)
src\MyClass.cpp(143): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<MyClass,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
3>          with
3>          [
3>              _Ty=MyClass
3>          ]
```

However, if I create a minimal class with deleted copy constructor, a default move constructor, I can create std::vector of such a class and emplace_back without problems. (I am not using push_back anywhere, but only emplace_back).

The error is triggered for the line in which I try to emplace_back with appropriate constructor types into this vector.

Line 143 is: vec.emplace_back();

Comment: The compiler should tell which part of your code the compilation error in `xmemory` is triggered from. Please read the error messages carefully, and if you want us to help, copy-paste them here.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406098/copy-assign-a-map-if-element-is-not-assignable/) somehow related? Interestingly there was a similar discussion just some minutes ago...

Comment: @Klaus That's only true before C++11, as the asker correctly notes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: I have added the error messages I am currently facing.

Comment: @a_pradhan There is not a single compiler error in there. These are all notes (and they are helpful, please keep them) but why did you leave out the real error?

Comment: @Klaus Yes, and the discussion is about a vector of a moveable type. What's the issue?

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Now I got it :-) Thanks!

Comment: @MaxLanghof I have added the entire error message. That's all I get.

Comment: Could you add the declaration of `MyClass`? The compiler is trying to move-construct during reallocation as hard as it can, but your class does not seem to have an eligible move-constructor. Did you accidentally declare it as `MyClass(const MyClass&&) = default;` or something?

Comment: I think a mcve would help a lot here...

Comment: @MaxLanghof I digged through the code, which is composition at work and lots of members were compound types themselves. It seems like the move constructor with `=default` doesn't seem to work but if I add blank bodies to the functions, the code compiles just fine. Thank you for the help, I will implement my own move constructors for all the types that have a default one.

Comment: That sounds like the class has a member which is non-moveable. In which case implementing a correct move constructor (without changing the rest of the class) is... Difficult to impossible.